# Why isn't my ac working after I jumped the car?

Tags: electrical, ac, troubleshooting, saturn, sc2

99 Saturn SC2

Ever since I jumped my car the AC hasn't been working. When I press the AC button the green light will turn on but I don't notice any additional drag on the system like I normally would. I also notice that when I press the recirculate button the air doesn't become more powerful like it used to. Essentially nothing happens at all when I press these buttons.

Comment: Perhaps you shorted something out while jumpstarting your car. Have you checked to make sure no fuses are blown?

Comment: I second @DaltonD here; it's likely to be a blown fuse or relay.  Also check that none of the wiring in the engine bay has been disturbed.

Comment: We've got a serious allergy to the answer box here, lol. I suppose I'll take one for the team.

Answer (score 1):

Check your fuses.

There's one box near the floor, passenger side, and one under the hood. AC should be in there somewhere but could be another (e.g. maybe a fan fuse, although I suspect the compressor since you're not noticing engine load). There's also an AC relay under the dash, if no fuses are blown, check / swap out that relay.

Make sure you didn't knock any wires loose too, esp. since the car is so old, a fragile connection may have come loose or snapped.

There's always the possibility that another issue with the AC just popped up coincidentally but look for the easy electrical stuff first.